# Java - lowercase a String outside quotes

Tags: java, string

I need to lowercase all characters in a String that are outside quotes.

It should support both single and double quotes.

For example:

A -> a

A'B' - > a'B'

A'A'A"A"A -> a'A'a"A"a

Is there any library function that does this, or do I have to parse the string myself? If so, what is the recommended way? Maybe use some fancy regex?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK there's no library function for this, and a regex-based solution will be slower and (IMO) harder to maintain than some old-school string manipulation:

Convert the string to a char array:

```
char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
```

Iterate over it, keeping track if you're inside the quotes or not:

```
boolean insideQuotes = false;
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    if (chars[i] == '\'' || chars[i] == '"') {
        insideQuotes = !insideQuotes;
    } else if (!insideQuotes) {
        chars[i] = Character.toLowerCase(chars[i]);
    }
}
```

and convert back to a string:

```
String newString = new String(chars);
```

Comment: Seems like a solid solution

Comment: thanks, but can I make it a little bit more complicated - I need that to support both single and double quotes

Comment: Sure - depending on your exact requirements (what happens to a single quote inside two double quotes? Will it be ignored?), you might need two booleans then, `insideSingleQuotes` and `insideDoubleQuotes`. Just keep track of the right 'state' while you're traversing through the char array.

Comment: Yes, sounds good. About your question - I think for my requirements I can assume quotes are valid, and if not - result can be undefined, that will make my life easier.